# How to make higher "aside" and "topnav"?

Tags: html, css

I tried to use "top" and "bottom" but it didn't work. How can I fix it ?

[Site](http://ksrf.tk/)

[image: It must to look like on this photo]

[HTML/CSS Code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/18gvQIF_yUvq3JW1uwtwUBC98mGLBzYoKxq82ed5DbMU/edit?usp=sharing)

```css
nav {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    
}

 .News {
    color: #6a70b3;
    font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, "sans-serif";
    font-size: 12.3333px;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: left;
    margin-right: 50%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-left: 14%;
}

section { /*Контент*/
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 12.8px;
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
}

section a:visited {
    color:#003399;
}

section a:hover {
    color: black;
}

aside { /*Sidebar*/
    padding: 5% 0.5%;
    margin: 0% auto;
    width: 20%;
    background-image: url(../images/side.PNG);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: auto;
    float: left;
}

aside li { /*Sidebar Список */
    font-family: Verdana, Arial , "sans-serif", helvetica;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    width: 70%;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 15px;
    z-index: 2;
    
}
/* Стиль верхней панели навигации */
.topnav {
    margin: 6.2%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    width: 80%;
    top: 20%;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    
}

/* Стиль ссылок навигации */
.topnav a {
    margin:0 auto;
    display:inline;
    margin-left:3px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    line-height: 7px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 700;
    float:left;
    font-family: verdana, "sans-serif", helvetica, arial;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 3;
}

/* Изменение цвета при наведении */
.topnav a:hover {
    color: orange;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none; /* Убираем маркеры */
    text-decoration: none; /* Убираем подчёркивание */
    margin-left: 0; /* Отступ слева в браузере IE и Opera */
    padding-left: 0; /* Отступ слева в браузере Firefox, Safari, Chrome */
}

ul a{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: darkblue;
}

ul a:hover{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:orange;
}

#mainText {
    text-align: center;
}

.border {
    color:black;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

footer { /*Подвал*/
        width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

footer a{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10.6667px;
    line-height: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#06C;
}

.footerline {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 1px;
    left: 0px;
    float: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>    
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
<title>Новости - Анонсы</title>
    </head>
<body>
     <header>
    <img src="images/headerfinal.png" class="Header" alt="Header">
    </header>
    <nav>
    <div class="topnav"> <!--Верхнее меню -->
  <a href="news.html">Новости</a>
  <a href="#top">О Суде</a>
  <a href="#top">Решения КС РФ</a>
  <a href="#top">Заседания КС РФ</a>
  <a href="#top">Контакты</a>
    </div>
    </nav>
<aside> <!-- Меню слева -->
<ul>
<li><a href="news.html">Новости</a></li>
<li><a href="#top">О Суде</a></li>
<li><a href="#top">Решения КС РФ</a></li>
<li><a href="#top">Заседания КС РФ</a></li>
<li><a href="#top">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<img src="images/gerb.gif" alt="Герб РФ">
    </aside>   
    <section> <!-- Основной текст -->
<div class="News"><h3>Новости - Анонсы</h3></div>
<br>
<p>10 ноября 2017 года Конституционный Суд РФ провозгласит Постановление по делу о проверке конституционности Федерального закона «О внесении изменений в отдельные законодательные акты РФ в части совершенствования законодательства о публичных мероприятиях»</p>
<br>
<p>( <a href="#top">подробнее...</a>)</p>
<br>
<p>7 ноября 2017 года Конституционный Суд РФ провозгласил Постановление по делу о проверке конституционности ряда положений Закона Республики Крым «Об особенностях регулирования имущественных и земельных отношений на территории Республики Крым»</p>
<br>
<p>( <a href="#top">подробнее...</a>)</p>

<br>
    <a href="#top">Посмотреть все новости</a>
<br>
    </section>

<br>
<br>
    <footer>
        <hr style="border:1px;width:60%; height:1px;background-color:black">
    <img src="images/footer.PNG" class=footerline alt="Footer">
        <a href="index.html">©Конституционный Суд Российской Федерации, 2008-2017</a>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: share your code here please

Comment: you need to fix your code errors, for example you left > off of the closing </html tag https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

Comment: It wants more details for a reason. Don't bypass warnings.

Comment: I've shared it. My left > was a mistake in word document, there is no such error on the site

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the position in your CSS, just like in your .footerline :)